# Redirect between 2 servers

Tags: apache, redirect

I have a website hosted on a **SERVER A**, using the domain `www.a.com`. I have another server (**SERVER B**), using the domain `www.b.com`.

On **SERVER A**, I created a redirect from `new.a.com` to `www.b.com`. The redirect is working fine, but **SERVER B** is not accepting the connection. If I open the browser and type  `www.b.com`, everything works fine. But if I try to access it from the redirect `new.a.com`, it doesn't work.

I checked apache logs but there is nothing there. Any ideas?

Comment: Not possible to know until we see your configuration for both the redirect and your www.b.com.  Do you have any IP filters on the B server that would only accept traffic from the Internet (public interface)?  To much information is missing.

Comment: Thanks @Nic3500! I will check the IP filter...I don't have full access to those servers, there is another company managing it, but they will not fix the problem. I will try to get more information...anything specific I should look for?

Comment: Ah ok, so you can only log in server A?  Login A and try `telnet serverB 80`.  This will validate that you can connect form A to B at the network level.  And add server A's configuration here, we might see the problem in your redirection (if network is ok).

Comment: Actually, I just have access to SERVER B. But the support team from SERVER A told me that the redirect is correct and they were able to connect to SERVER B using the telnet idea

Comment: ok, so open your browser with console (like F12 on Chrome, or user fiddler) and make sure you are receiving a redirect 301 or 302 from new.a.com going to www.b.com.  If you do get the redirection header and still cannot connect to www.b.com, it has to be a networking problem.  Verifying the received redirection header will also help you identify any extra url or header the redirection might have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that was a problem with the secure connection. Site `www.b.com` has a SSL certificate, so it needs to be served using **HTTPS**. The problem was that `www.a.com` was redirecting to `http://www.b.com` instead of `https://`.

I was able to setup apache on `www.b.com` to force the redirect to always use **HTTPS** and that solved the problem.